# Stopping GCP jobs when credit runs out

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I got some credits for using GCP.  It asked me for a credit card before accessing.  Since it is quite tricky to monitor the cost in real time, I hope to set up a circuit breaker such that once my credit runs out, all my VM instance jobs will cease running.  I understand there will still be some small charges for space and static IP, but they are OK.

Is such a circuit breaker feasible?  I checked some FAQs on budget alerts, e.g., https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets, but there appears no mentioning of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to be [notified progammatically](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets-programmatic-notifications) by creating a budget then using pub/sub which that'll push a Cloud Function to stop your resources. Here is an [example](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/notify) based on the previous suggestion.